# Why does bundler influence the execution of a native C++ library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler, ruby-ffi

I have written a `Ruby gem` that makes use of the most recent version of `FFI` to access a (as well self written) shared object library. I am using `ruby 2.0.0p247` in conjunction with `rvm 1.21.12`.

My gem includes an 'executable' in /bin thats works as expected, reads in some data given by the user, and calls one function in my shared object library that in turn calls one function in an external API library. Everything works fine.

If I execute the exact same code of my 'executable' inside an `RSpec test`, or inside a `Rails console`, the underlying API components fails. It seems to fail during a `SSL operation` where a `RSA private key` read from a `PKCS#12` container is used to digitally sign a piece of XML.

I was able to break everything down to `bundle`r. If I execute my (working) 'executable' using `bundler`, it fails with the same error that I see inside `RSpec` and `Rails`.

I crosschecked `ENV` variables already and set them directly at the execution time. No change.

So the question is: What does `bundler` do to the execution environment, that lets fail my underlying API component.

Where can I start to look for errors?

Any hints on that are welcome. Regards
Felix

Comment: can you please show the errors?

Comment: I only get an error message from the underlying C++ API component. It states: `error:06069097:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_encrypt:operation not initialized`

Comment: `bundle exec` does change some environment variables.  You can see what's changed by running this command from your project directory: `diff -u <(env|sort) <(bundle exec env|sort)`.

How are you setting the environment variables at execution time? Is it possible that your settings are getting overridden at a later point?

Comment: I had the same suspicion. As it turned out, it was'nt a bundler issue. The real problem was related to the openssl version thats beeing installed by the latest Debian. Removing it and installing 0.9.8y from source solved the problem.